# error al instalar dingo/api

Tags: php, laravel, api, rest

estoy tratando de instalar dingo/api para una api rest en laravel 5.1 pero cuando ejecuto `composer require dingo/api:1.0.x@dev` me lanza este error:

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

> Problem 1
>
> - dingo/api 1.0.x-dev requires dingo/blueprint 0.2.* -> satisfiable by dingo/blueprint[0.2.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
>
>   - Conclusion: don't install dingo/api v1.0.0-beta3
>   - Conclusion: don't install dingo/api v1.0.0-beta2
>   - Conclusion: remove phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.1.0
>   - Installation request for dingo/api 1.0.x@dev -> satisfiable by dingo/api[1.0.x-dev, v1.0.0-beta1, v1.0.0-beta2, v1.0.0-beta3].
>   - Conclusion: don't install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.1.0
>   - dingo/api v1.0.0-beta1 requires phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 2.0.* -> satisfiable by phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock[2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.0.4].
>   - Can only install one of: phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock[2.0.0, 3.1.0].
>   - Can only install one of: phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock[2.0.1, 3.1.0].
>   - Can only install one of: phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock[2.0.2, 3.1.0].
>   - Can only install one of: phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock[2.0.3, 3.1.0].
>   - Can only install one of: phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock[2.0.4, 3.1.0].
>   - Installation request for phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock (locked at 3.1.0) -> satisfiable by phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock[3.1.0].

```
Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

no se a qué se deba esto, gracias de antemano...

aquí el contenido de mi composer.json:

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
    "dingo/api": "1.0.x@dev"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
    "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
        "tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
}
}
```

Comment: Agrega el contenido de tu composer.json a la pregunta (editándola) para poder darte una mejor respuesta.

Comment: si listo ya edite la pregunta

Comment: Hola el error se puede deber a una falla en la compatibilidad, si usas xampp o wampserver debes usar la versión que contenga php7 o en su defecto php5, para no tener problemas a futuro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok conseguí la respuesta solo debía agregar al require del composer.json el `phpdocumentor/reflection: 3.x@dev` y luego el `dingo/api:1.0.x@dev` y ejecutar composer update y listo todo funcionó bien, así quedó el composer.json:

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
    "phpdocumentor/reflection": "3.x@dev",
    "dingo/api": "1.0.x@dev"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
    "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
        "tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add "phpdocumentor/reflection": "3.x@dev" under "require": { } in composer.json and run a composer update

"require": {

```
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
    "phpdocumentor/reflection": "3.x@dev"
```

},

$ composer update
$ composer require dingo/api:1.0.x@dev

after successful command this will add "dingo/api": "1.0.x@dev" under require.

"require": {

```
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
    "phpdocumentor/reflection": "3.x@dev",
    "dingo/api": "1.0.x@dev"
```

}

Comment: Hi Mohammad. This site is for Spanish communication in all content: questions, answers, comments, etc. Please edit your answers and use Spanish, otherwise the post will be removed.